# Derby in-memory db: running out of memory on select into - statements

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

I have to use a derby with some huge tables in a project. To get some performance, I'm selecting document IDs from three different tables into one huge table for look-up of the doc type.

Basically a very simple query:

```
"INSERT INTO DOC_TYPES SELECT DOC_ID, 1 FROM TYPE_A_DOCUMENT"
"INSERT INTO DOC_TYPES SELECT DOC_ID, 2 FROM TYPE_B_DOCUMENT"
"INSERT INTO DOC_TYPES SELECT DOC_ID, 3 FROM TYPE_C_DOCUMENT"
```

When I run this in "normal" mode, with the derby on my hard drive, it takes about 1 Minute to process and I end up with about 6.5 Million rows in the DB (huge, I know...)

Anyway, the database is still way to slow for my taste, so I was trying to run everything in-memory. Unfortunately, even with 4GB heap size (the full DB on my hard drive never exceeds 1GB), the operation results pretty fast in a "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError".

I don't really see any alternatives or workarounds to solve this problem. Derby doesn't support materialized views and doing this in Java (SELECT, interate resultset, INSERT) would take hours...

You also can't "chunk up" the statement, since Derby doesn't seem to support LIMIT.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Do you perform these inserts in a single transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to create chunks by modulo id, set the second value of the modulo operation to the number of chunks (n) you need. and repeat the comparision from 0..(n-1)

```
INSERT INTO DOC_TYPES SELECT DOC_ID, 1 FROM TYPE_A_DOCUMENT WHERE DOC_ID % 2 = 0
INSERT INTO DOC_TYPES SELECT DOC_ID, 1 FROM TYPE_A_DOCUMENT WHERE DOC_ID % 2 = 1
```

and commit the transaction for each insert.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea to chunk the stuff up. Thanks ;)